Impossible to set up NX + NUXT typescript workspace properly and use NX libs
I am trying to start a new project with npx create-nx-workspace@latest --preset=nuxt, then create a nx lib with npx nx generate library --bundler=vite, and then use that new lib in my nuxt project.
my project's structure is something like:
| root
  | apps
    | site
      tsconfig.json // this one imports tsconfig.base.json
  | libs
    | services
      | my-service
        | src
          index.ts
  tsconfig.base.json

I am setting a path on tsconfig.base.json like:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "."
    "path": {
      "@services/*": ["./libs/services/*/src/index.ts"]
    }
  }
}

I tried everything: setting typescript.tsConfig stuff on the nuxt.config.ts... using nested tsconfig files... and nothing works properly to resolve the paths.
My VSCode can resolve the @services module (I can click on it and jump to the correct index file), but the eslint keeps marking it as unresolved:

Plus, I get this erros when starting the dev server:

I have no idea how to set the tsconfig paths properly.... kinda desperate already...

Yep, same here ...
